# How can I use interfaces to allow for more than 1 struct type to make code more useable?

Tags: reflection, go, struct, interface, slice

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
type BetaKey struct {
    Id           int64  `json:"-"`
    IssuerId     int64  `json:"-"          db:"issuer_id"`
    SubjectEmail string `json:"-"          db:"subject_email"`
    IssuedTime   int64  `json:"-"          db:"issued_time"`
    ExpiryTime   int64  `json:"expiryTime" db:"expiry_time"`
    Betakey      string `json:"accessKey"`
    Description  string `json:"description"`
}
```

And within the same package I have a function that returns a slice of `BetaKey`:

```
func buildResults(query string) ([]BetaKey, error) {
    results := []BetaKey{}
    rows, err := sql.DB.Queryx(query)
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var bk BetaKey
        err := rows.StructScan(&bk)
        if err != nil {
            return results, err
        }
        results = append(results, bk)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }
    return results, nil
}
```

Is it possible for me to rewrite this function so that it takes in a query string but also a type of `BetaKey` as `interface{}`, and returns a slice of `interface{}` so that I can reuse the code instead of copy pasting this into every package because it is literally the same but the only difference is the name of the struct that changes.

Is this possible? And also is this advised? If not, then why?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just learn about reflection on Golang.

Comment: I know how to get the name of the struct with reflection. And I know I can convert the interface with .(type) syntax. But I still do not how to rewrite the function above to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics could be used to implement such thing, but Go does not support generics. To do what you want in Go, you need to use reflection.

You may change your function to take 1 additional parameter, a [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) for example which designates type of values the individual rows should be loaded into.

Then you can use [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) to create a new value of this type and acquire a pointer to it. You can use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to obtain the pointer value as a type of `interface{}` from the [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) value. This `interface{}` wrapping the pointer can now be passed to `Rows.StructScan()`.

And if you want the result slice to hold non-pointer values, you can use [`reflect.Indirect()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect) to get the pointed value (and another `reflect.Interface()` to extract the struct value as an `interface{}`).

Example code:

```
func buildResults(query string, t reflect.Type) ([]interface{}, error) {
    results := []interface{}{}
    rows, err := sql.DB.Queryx(query)
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        val := reflect.New(t)
        err := rows.StructScan(val.Interface())
        if err != nil {
            return results, err
        }
        i_ := reflect.Indirect(val)
        result = append(result, i_.Interface())
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }
    return results, nil
}
```

The heart of it is the `for` block:

```
val := reflect.New(t)                   // A pointer to a new value (of type t)
err := rows.StructScan(val.Interface()) // Pass the pointer to StructScan
if err != nil {
    return results, err
}
i_ := reflect.Indirect(val)             // Dereference the pointer
result = append(result, i_.Interface()) // And add the non-pointer to the result slice
```

Here's how you can test it:

```
type BetaKey struct {
    Id   string
    Name string
}

type AlphaKey struct {
    Id     string
    Source string
}

r, err := buildResults("", reflect.TypeOf(AlphaKey{}))
fmt.Printf("%T %+v %v\n", r[0], r, err)

r, err = buildResults("", reflect.TypeOf(BetaKey{}))
fmt.Printf("%T %+v %v\n", r[0], r, err)
```

Output:

```
main.AlphaKey [{Id:aa Source:asource} {Id:aa Source:asource} {Id:aa Source:asource}] <nil>
main.BetaKey [{Id:aa Name:aname} {Id:aa Name:aname} {Id:aa Name:aname}] <nil>
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4u0RrsUxMK).

**Notes:**

The above solution will return a value of type of `[]interface{}` whose elements will be of *static* type `interface{}` and their dynamic type will be the one specified by the `reflect.Type` argument. So for example if you call it with type:

```
bt := reflect.TypeOf(BetaKey{})
```

The values in the result slice will have dynamic type `BetaKey` so you can safely [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) them like this:

```
results, err := buildResults("some query", bt)
if err == nil {
    for _, v := range results {
        key := v.(BetaKey)
        // key is of type BetaKey, you may use it like so
    }
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

To learn more about reflection, read the blog post:

[**The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection**](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Comment: Thank you good sir! I see you like StarCraft on your profile. You didn't by any chance play iccup? ^^

Comment: If I wanted to json.Marshal the result, would I need to convert the interface{} type to BetaKey with .(type) syntax first? Or is it possible to json.Marshal the interface?

Comment: @Alex In Starcraft (Broodwar) I was a "BGH guy" (played Big Game Hunters), no iccup, but nowadays when I play, I only play StarCraft II of course.

Comment: @Alex No need any conersion or type assertion if you want to marshal the result, `json.Marshal()` takes an argument of type `interface{}` anyway, and that's what you have. If you try to pass a non-interface type to `Marshal()`, a wrapper `interface{}` value will be created automatically.

Comment: Cool thanks alot for the help! This was very helpful! I have not played starcraft for years. Oh the nostalgia brood war gives! Let me know if you want to play starcraft 2 some day!

Comment: I get error: type []interface {} is not an expression, for the line with the expression "results := []interface{}", both the compiler and GoSublime does not like it, I don't understand why.

Comment: It works with "var results []interface{}", but not results := []interface{}

Comment: @Alex Sorry, that was a typo from my part. The slice type is `[]interface{}`, so the literal to create a value of this must be **`[]interface{}{}`**. See edited answer.

Comment: That makes sense! It's like someMap := map[string]interface{}{} Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I write a little example using json, instead of sql rows. You can try to develop from this code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "encoding/json"
)

type A struct {
    AField int `json:"a"`
}

type B struct {
    BField string `json:"b"`
}

func build(str string, typ reflect.Type) interface{} {
    results := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), 0, 10)
    for i:=0; i < 5; i++ {
        res := reflect.New(typ)
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), res.Interface())
        results = reflect.Append(results, res.Elem())
    }
    return results.Interface();
}

func main() {
    a := build("{ \"a\": 15 }", reflect.TypeOf(&A{}))
    fmt.Printf("%T : %V\n", a, a)
    b := build("{ \"b\": \"my string\" }", reflect.TypeOf(&B{}))
    fmt.Printf("%T : %V\n", b, b)
}
```

[Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NTFPvK3VHe)

Comment: What if I do not know the length and capacity of the slice beforehand? I am used to just create slices and adding stuff into them dynamically without saying anything about length and capacity

Comment: no problem, you can put any number. It growth automatically.